# Custom attributes for core/button depending on the parent using Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

I have a custom block named Payment Buttons. Inside that I want to add as many buttons as I need and each button should have a dropdown with a selectable list of links.

the challenge here is to detect the buttons are in a specific parent and add that dropdown to only those buttons, not to all button components.

I’m ready to explain more if it’s required. Can anyone give any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly it sounds like you'd be better off creating your own custom inner block to use, instead of the core block. If you want to inherit a (supported) theme's styling for those blocks you can add the `wp-element-button` class to your buttons.